# usePreventScroll causes useLayoutEffect warning in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-aria

I'm learning Next.js and I'm trying to integrate the `@react-aria/overlays` package in my project. I have a layout component, where I'm simply invoking the `usePreventScroll` method like this:

```
   usePreventScroll({
        isDisabled: true
    });
```

This layout component is used in my `_app.js`.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import * as gtag from '../lib/gtag'

import 'styles/vendor.scss';
import 'styles/globals.scss';

import Layout from 'components/layout';

import { SSRProvider } from '@react-aria/ssr';

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
      <SSRProvider>
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </SSRProvider>
  )
}
```

export default App;

When going to my browser and loading a page, it gives me the following error:

```
Warning: useLayoutEffect does nothing on the server, because its effect cannot be encoded into the server renderer's output format. This will lead to a mismatch between the initial, non-hydrated UI and the intended UI. To avoid this, useLayoutEffect should only be used in components that render exclusively on the client. See https://reactjs.org/link/uselayouteffect-ssr for common fixes.
    at Layout (/home/bas/projects/test-website/build/server/pages/_app.js:718:3)
    at div
    at $c5f9596976ab8bd94c5879001549a3e$var$OverlayContainerDOM (/home/bas/projects/test-website/node_modules/@react-aria/overlays/dist/main.js:864:7)
    at ModalProvider (/home/bas/projects/test-website/node_modules/@react-aria/overlays/dist/main.js:810:5)
    at OverlayProvider
    at SSRProvider (/home/bas/projects/test-website/node_modules/@react-aria/ssr/dist/main.js:33:13)
    at UIContextProvider (/home/bas/projects/test-website/build/server/pages/_app.js:1144:74)
    at ManagedUIContext (/home/bas/projects/test-website/build/server/pages/_app.js:1105:3)
    at App (/home/bas/projects/test-website/build/server/pages/_app.js:5171:3)
    at AppContainer (/home/bas/projects/test-website/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:23:748)
```

What's the problem here and how would I be able to solve it?

I tried wrapping the the `Layout` component in the packages `<SSRProvider>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next js is computes your 1st page on server. so it does not understand browser scroll or localstorage or other browser api.
you can add a check in your code block if window object is present or execution is running in server and then execute `usePreventDefault`.

```
    import {useIsSSR} from '@react-aria/ssr';

    function Layout() {
       let isSSR = useIsSSR();
 
       useEffect(() => {
         !isSSR && usePreventScroll({ ... }) 
       }, [isSSR])
    }
```

Comment: I think you ment `usePreventScroll` instead of `usePreventDefault`, but it didn't work out. I got the following error `Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.`

Comment: Thanks for the help , but with the updated answer it gives me a `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:`

Comment: Is it not a functional component? can you share where you are calling the method.

Comment: In my `_app.js` . I'll paste the file in.

Comment: I mean is your layout component, where you are calling `usePreventScroll` is not functional component?

Comment: then it must be in componentDidMount, shouldnt re-render. Just add window check without useIsSSR hook. `componentDidMount() { window && usePreventScrolll() }`

Comment: I'm sorry, `layout` is actually a functional component. Where it does work properly by checking window. Why can't I use `useIsSSR` in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

You can dynamically load the component and disable SSR:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/hello3'),
  { ssr: false }
)

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR />
      <p>HOME PAGE is here!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

The code example has been taken from the [NextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr). If that's not your thing, you can call the hook or render the component as long as `processs.browser` is true.

Comment: How would I call the `usePreventScroll` using that? Would I need an extra component?

Comment: No, you would only call dynamic() when you import/use the component. If you don't want to dynamically import the component just to work around SSR, then render your Layout component conditionally when process.browser is true.